# When is a cubic polynomial a cube?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

I've been researching cubes and I'm trying to solve this Diophantine equation over the integers.

$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = y^3$$where a, b, c, d are parameters for a given $n$. For example, for $n = 5$, you have$$5x^3 + 30x^2 + 90x + 100 = y^3$$

Is there any way to solve this Diophantine equation? Or does anyone know any references or links to point me to? (Either for general $a,b,c,d$ or for the specific one above). Thanks!

Like I said above, $a, b, c, d$ are functions of n:
$$a = n$$
$$b = (3/2)n(n-1)$$
$$c = (1/2)n(2n-1)(n-1)$$
$$d = (1/4)n^2(n-1)^2$$

It's theorized that there are no solutions (to this specific one). But I want to prove it. Surely, I can't check for every single x, I'm mainly looking for a bound on x as a function of n. Essentially, "After some finite x, it will never be a cube" ...

Comment: Because it's cubic, barring various degeneracies it'll be an _elliptic curve_, and many things are known about  _rational_ points (Mordell-Weil), while _integral_ points are subtler. Searching on "elliptic curve" should give you a broader context.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896661/cubic-polynomial-equal-to-a-cube

Comment: @WillJagy yeah, I posted on mse and mo

Comment: You posted on m.se and MO without linking each to the other. That's rude.

Comment: lol didn't know I had to link them.

Comment: @Derek actually  there are good reasons for doing so, as you can imagine (what's " $|o|$ "?)

Comment: @Pietro: I thinks he means the (textspeak) shorthand for "laughing out loud", it's not a Mathematical symbol!

Comment: You probably know already that $P_n(x) := ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is identically
a cube if $n=0$ or $\pm1$.  Otherwise $P_n(x)$ has no repeated factors
so $y^3=P_n(x)$ is an elliptic curve and thus has only finitely many
integer solutions, but it can be hard to provably list them all
and we don't expect to be abls to do it uniformly in $n$.
I suppose you know already that $x=(1-n)/2$ always works if $n$ is odd, 
while both $x=-n/2$ and $x=1-(n/2)$ work if $n$ is even.  There are also 
occasional sporadic solutions like $x=-34,-22,3,15$ for $n=20$.

Comment: Thanks @NoamD.Elkies. Yes, I was able to find solutions for $n = 20$. It's also best when $x > 0$, when $x < 0$, it's quite trivial. Thanks for the help, I'll check up on elliptical curves.